# Value of dynamically generated Textbox not changing in Voila Render mode in ipywidgets

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, ipywidgets, voila

I am generating  Textboxes dynamically in ipywidgets. The use case is, in a given tab, multiple cities will be selected from a list of checkboxes, and then based on selection, a table containing city name and priority (editable) will generated dynamically. User can edit the priority of a city in the table. Once done, user will hit the submit button, after which a CSV containing city names and their updated priorities should be created.

The problem is , when I execute in Jupyter Notebook, things are working fine, but when I execute using Voila Render button in Jupyter Notebook, I am not getting the updated priorities, I get the default value when I try to do hbox.value.

Any help will be highly appreciated!!

Comment: Your issue seems to spell out a case that happens when you are not handling observing updates as needed for current ipywidgets, which Voila needs for interaction.  There's a lot of outdated code around that people try and use despite the fact ipywidgets has changed a lot recently. You'd have to share a toy example to either rule that out as being the issue or to get specific advice on how to do things. Please see under 'Help others reproduce the problem' in [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)